# VBA Refresh all sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have a VBA file that generates sheets from a template and uses a seperate sheet for it's data.

It works however the update function doesn't update like I expected it to.

In the template I define a value of a cell based upon the name of the sheet

```
=MID(CELL("filename");FIND("]";CELL("filename"))+1;LENGTH(CELL("filename")))
```

The loop in VBA creates new sheets based upon the import file and template.

It generates all sheets like I want but it doesn't update the sheetname cell.
I added this in VBA:

```
Sub Workbook_RefreshAll()
    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
End Sub
```

This doesn't do anything. If I refresh manually it refreshes all sheets based upon the selected sheet.

-----------------EDIT---------------------

```
Option Explicit

Sub AddSheets()
Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim wksNew As Worksheet
Dim rngCell As Range
Dim MySheet As String
Dim countOfEmpty As Long

'Loop voor verwijderen duplicaten
Dim v As Variant, c As Variant
    v = Worksheets(Sheets("Template").Range("L41").Value).Range("B5:B500").Value
    With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        For Each c In v
            .Item(c) = 1
        Next c
        Worksheets(Sheets("Template").Range("L41").Value).Range("K5").Resize(.Count) = Application.Transpose(.Keys)
    End With

'Loop voor maken sheets
MySheet = Sheets("Template").Range("L41").Value
Set wks = Sheets(MySheet)
Set rngCell = wks.Range("K5")

Do While True
    If IsEmpty(rngCell) Then
        countOfEmpty = countOfEmpty + 1
        If countOfEmpty = 2 Then Exit Do
    Else
        countOfEmpty = 0
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Template").Copy after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
        ActiveSheet.Name = rngCell.Value
    End If
    Set rngCell = rngCell.Offset(1)
Loop

End Sub
Sub Workbook_RefreshAll()
    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
End Sub
```

Comment: RefreshAll is for external connections. `Application.Calculate` does what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the full code, there's a few things that are jumping out to me

The formula appears to be using ";" instead of "." and LENGTH instead of LEN, I'll assume it's a copy / paste issue.

ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll refreshes all data connections / external references and is the same as clicking on Data -> Refresh All, so it won't cause your formula to be evaluated.

The other consideration is formulas are assessed to determine if they need to be evaluated due to a change in the worksheet. I have found this can cause the formula like what you have to not be evaluated even when a change occurs.

I think the easiest approach would be something like this:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    ws.Calculate
Next ws
```

Please be aware that this forces the calculation on each worksheet (in sequence) so this is not a good solution if you had worksheet formulas referencing other worksheet formulas, however in your case I believe this should work fine.

Comment: Please see my edit. I have added the entire code. Due to the fact that I'm working in a different language the formulas use different words.